# React IF - ELSE Link does a real load of the page

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and try to navigate to another route 
using `<Link>`.

My problem is that a click on the link results in a real 
page load instead of a SPA like navigation.

Ive noticed that this happens because i wrapped the link in a if else block.

**This works:**

```
<Link to="/login">Login</Link>
```

**This does not work:**

```
let loginOrLogout = (isUserLoggedIn) ? 
   (<Link to="/logout">Logout</Link>) :
   (<Link to="/login">Login</Link>);
{loginOrLogout}
```

Comment: You mean you get two differents behaviors with and without a if else block? Please share your code

Comment: My question is updated

Comment: use normal if condition and check if you get inside proper conditional block using console output , this will give you clear idea. Also set loginOrLogout  to null before assignment and console.it before the return.. and check if you get null or component

Comment: is the variable `loginOrLogout` well created in the `render()` method?

Comment: @abhirathore2006 done. But this does not help. It does not work.

Comment: @DamienLeroux what you mean by "well created". It is created in the render method before return.

Comment: @dknaack this is the way to debug,  try to findout if the loginOrLogout contains correct link before render, Link works just fine. its somewhere login getting wrong data

Comment: Sorry French expression ^^. Is the variable `loginOrLogout` created inside the `render()` method or in another method called for example `componentWillReceiveProps` or outside a React class?

Comment: @DamienLeroux no problem :) The variable gets created in the render method.

Comment: @abhirathore2006 besides the different "data-reactid" the output in the browser is identically

Answer (score 0):

Try a React stateless component like:

```
    function LoginOrLogout(props) {
        if (props.isUserLoggedIn) {
            return <Link to="/logout">Logout</Link>;
        }

        return <Link to="/login">Login</Link>;
    }
```

call in the render method:

```
    <LoginOrLogout isUserLoggedIn={isUserLoggedIn}>
```